# Access 2007 problem

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

I can't open .mdb files or create new one. Every time I try to open a new or existing file I get a password login prompt and my host login from Windows doesn't work.. how can I reset my Access :(!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a default workgroup file that has a password set on the admin account. Search your hard drive for other system.mdw files and try running the workgroup administrator and pointing it to one of these other system.mdw files.

Alternatively, find out which system.mdw is the default workgroup file and rename it. When you run Access the next time, it should recreate a new default workgroup file with no password on the admin account.

Keep in mind that if you are working with an MDB that actually uses Jet user-level security, changing the workgroup might make it unusable.